# what is a magnitude of an element in an vector? how to compute this magnitude?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

i am learning [the DeepLearningBook](https://deeplearningbook.org), in which chapter 2 says

> One other norm that commonly arises in machine learning is the $L^{\infty}$
>   norm, also known as the max norm. This norm simplifies to the absolute
>   value of the element with the largest magnitude in the vector

$$
\begin{equation}
    \left\lVert{\boldsymbol{\mathit{x}}}\right\rVert_\infty = \max_i |x_i|.
\end{equation}
$$

what is a magnitude of an element in an vector? how to compute this magnitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnitude of an element in a vector is whatever makes sense at the time and will be explicitly defined for whatever context you are working in in the event that it is a more exotic scenario.

Generally, in most normal scenarios where you are working with the $L^\infty$ norm, you would be working in $\Bbb R^n$ or $\Bbb C^n$ or something similar for your vector space in which case the magnitude of a specific entry of a vector is very simply the "absolute value" which we are used to using every day of our lives.

For example if the vector was $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-7\\3\end{bmatrix}$, the $L^\infty$ norm of this vector would be $7$ as this is the largest absolute value of the entries of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

If your vector $x$ is $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, then you oick th $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ for which $\lvert x_i\rvert$ is the greatest. Then $\lVert x\rVert=\lvert x_i\rvert$.